# Formik FieldArray pulling Values

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am trying to pull the value of the field in a FieldArray using Formik. Being that it's a wizard form I had to create a custom component to render it within my form. By doing this I am able to pull in the Formik props using `useFormikContext();`. I'm having difficulties pulling the value (boolean) which I am trying to use to determine if the checkbox is checked or not.

**Initial Value:**

```
const initialValues = {

  // step two
  processors: false,
};
```

**Yup Validation:**

```
const stepTwoValidation = Yup.object({
  processors: Yup.bool().oneOf([true], 'Must choose at least one processor.'),
});
```

**Custom Component:**

```
const Processors = (props) => {
  const { values } = useFormikContext();

  return (
    <FieldArray
      name='processors'
      render={(values) => (
        <>
          {processors.map((processor) => (
            <Col lg={4}>
              <div className='form-group' key={processor.id}>
                <div className='form-check'>
                  <label className={`onboard__processor-label ${values.processor ? 'is-checked' : ''}`}>
                    <input name='processors' type='checkbox' value={processor.id} checked={values.processor} />
                    {processor.name}
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </Col>
          ))}
        </>
      )}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: you're using `fieldArray`, so your `initialValue` should be an array. your input should have `i` in their name `name='processors[i]'`. `i` you can get from the map array method `processors.map((processor, i)`

Comment: I've done this and it didnt work